# Creating a new Image this way

Tags: javascript, image, element

I came across this way of creating this 'Image' element,
and wanted to know the use cases of it, and how it works.

```
(new Image).src = "http://localhost:3000/image.png"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would not recommend creating elements like this. This way you **nearly** have no possibility to access and change them.

Comment: I've noticed some other scripts that use this way.
How do they even put the Image element on the document after creating it this way?
Are there any advantages?

Comment: [Preloading/-fetching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetching). This requests the image so it is available in the cache. The browser fetches the image in the background and when you later need it, it will be available immediately.

Comment: @LironAvital there is a function called `appendChild`, which can be used to append a newly created element to a tag (the body tag, for instance) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement for more information.

Comment: @DeniJuric Yes, but in case of pre-fetching we don't need the instance of the image. We only want the browser to get the image for later use.

Comment: @DeniJuric Yeah i know `appendChild`, but if you tried putting an element created this way in the document with `appendChild` you'd get an error.

@Andreas So how do you refer to the image afterwards? Just by calling the src again in a regular <img> element?

Comment: @LironAvital _"So how do you refer to the image afterwards?"_ - Yes, but now the browser already has the image in his cache and can use this instead of first asking the server for that image.